# Working on a Core Data store on two computers at the same time (or making sure it is only open on one computer at the same time)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Can I somehow work on two computers with the same Core Data store? This could, I presume, lead to some incompatibilities during saving. What is the best way to deal with this?

Also, let's say I want to avoid the pain of having to worry about this. How would I make sure that only one computer can work on a particular Core Data store at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience with Core Data I do not believe that the framework was designed to be used in a multi user (or distributed) environment. I found [this interesting post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/319446-core-data-multiuser.html) on CocoaBuilder which might help you shape your thoughts on the matter. It's dated July 2012, so it's pretty recent and also discusses some interesting other technologies that are available.

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, you can work on multiple devices on the same store with one of Apple's own core technologies. It's called **iCloud**.

Sure, technically speaking there are several copies of the store on the devices as well as the logs in iCloud, but the effect would be the same.

Fortunately, iCloud syncing includes some clever mechanism to merge multiple versions if possible (if not, you have to decide which one to give preference).

*Only caveat: in my experience iCloud with Core Data has been far from reliable when using the published information for implementation.*